# Sequence Diagram - Lifeline modelled as Class or System

Tags: uml, sequence, diagram

is it allowed to draw a sequence diagram with classes and systems as lifelines.

**For example:**

I want to model a part of the domain logic with a sequence diagram. Can I model a the lifeline once as a class and once as a whole system (remote system or a whole layer/jar file)?

**Example-1:**

There is the Class Scheduler which invokes the FileDownloader class which calls a FileServer? So I have the "Scheduler" (Class) the "FileDownloader" (Class) and the "FileServer"(remote System) as a lifeline.

**Example-2:**

Or I have a Class called Scheduler which invokes the "AccountingService" which calls the "Persistence Layer" which calls the "Database"
So I have the "Scheduler" (Class) the "AccountingService"(Class) the "PersistenceyLayer" (Whole Layer or .jar File) and the "Database" (System).

Is it allowed to mix these up in a sequence diagram. In some descriptions about sequence diagrams there would only modelled classes that call classes or systems that call systems.

Thanks.

Comment: In sequence diagrams, displaying a class means "when I make an instance / object of this class, this activities occur".

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "System" ? In UML there is not definition of system. You probably mean System as a name of Class or Component, or is it a stereotype? If yes, you can mix it.
Jar file is artifact. Artifact is Classifier as well. If artifact plays role in internal or communication structure, it can be represented by lifeline as well.

Lifeline represents instance of specific type which participate in interaction. Referenced type could be any connectable element from classifier owning interaction (sequence diagram, for example Class, Component or other types of classifiers).
To learn more about UML, I recommend you to read UML superstructure specification document.
Dowload it for free from omg.. [UML Superstructure](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)

Comment: Obviously the questionner mixes classes and instances. For his level of understanding the subject, using of common term "system" instead of "component" or "role" is forgivable. On the other hand, it is obvious that he won't manage the UML standard descriptions, they would be too abstract for him. I would advice a user help for some UML tool. For example, Visual Paradigm UML. It is not so full, but is MUCH more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Lifeline usually represents a role (it can be what you call *system* or even a human being), or an *object*. Notice, not class but its instance! Lifeline represents any thing with some behaviour. Classes mostly describe not their own behaviour, but behaviour of their instances. You'll have a class as a timeline only when you are modelling its static fields and functions. Or when you are in JS or similar language and your class is really a *prototype*

So, mixing of large and small objects, components or roles is absolutely OK. It is a part of standard UML usage. But do not mix instances and classes if you are modelling for "traditional" languages! Are you sure that it is the *class* "Sheduler" that invokes something, and not an instance myBestSheduler of this class?

Answer (score 0):

In sequence diagrams, displaying a class means "when I make an instance / object of this class, this activities occur".

And, other external stuff, that interact with your program, like the users ("actors"), Shared Libraries /DLLs, Web Services, Operating System, Network, whatever ...

... are considered objects ("instance of a class").

A Sequence Diagram, is composed by several objects, each one, with its own "Lifeline" or "TimeLine", that interact among them, (several "Lifeline (s)").